# Adding granular permissions to gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I've been wondering if it's possible to add granular permissions to edit/modify a gridview?  For example, I have a group of users that I want to only grant delete permissions from a given gridview while everyone else will have edit/save/view permissions.

I haven't come across this on MSDN (it's quite possible that I'm not looking in the right place).  Is this functionality even possible out of the box or via some code hack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the following to your GridView.OnInit() method:

In C#...

```
if(User.IsInRole("YourRole"))
{
    GridView.Columns[0].Visible = true;
    GridView1.Columns[0].Enabled = true;
}
else{
    GridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;
    GridView1.Columns[0].Enabled = false;
}
```

That is assuming that Column 0 is your delete column.